# Django-registration - uncomplete stuff

Tags: django, django-registration, django-profiles

I'm using django-registration and django-profiles and after having confirm the registration, I meet a 404 when I try to access to the page `http://example.com/profiles/fox/` -

I saw with the debug_toolbar all the queries that have been made and saw one on the table I defined in the settings `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'tglr.UserProfile'` - the query on this model returns ... nothing.

It looks like that the registration confirmation did not do its job.

What do i miss ?

thank you for your help

regards

**edit**: if I add the missing record in the UserProfile table all goes well - this really seems to confirm the behavior I met.

Comment: no i dont set a signal  i thought that was provided as the requirement was to use a dedicated model with the AUTH setting . i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a UserProfile record wasn't created when you registered the user.  [The page on user profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) in the Django manual details how a `post_save` signal can automatically insert a UserProfile record when a user is created.  Specifically, try adding this somewhere near you user model:

```
# FROM THE ABOVE LINK: 
# in models.py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Thank's a lot - that perfect !